# Override Change Comments change list

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is it possible to override the Comments change list and detail view in the django admin so that I can get a string representation of object commented on, such as the title of the blog post that was commented on as apposed to the Object ID? I assume Object ID comes [from here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/models/#django.contrib.comments.models.Comment.object_pk) I am looking to see if I can query that object id and display the title from where the comment is attached to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mipadi's advice for using `__unicode__` is still applicable. Since the comments framework utilizes generic foreign keys, relying directly on a particular field name on the model (such as `title`) is a bad idea. If one generically-related object doesn't have the field, everything will come crashing down. If you instead rely on `__unicode__` (which you should be adding to every model anyways), you'll have much greater reliability.

The code below details how to add a unicode representation of the related object to the comments changelist. It requires subclassing the default `CommentsAdmin`, adding a method to return the unicode representation of the related object, and then replaces the default `object_pk` in `list_display` with that method.

```
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment
from django.contrib.comments.admin import CommentsAdmin

class CustomCommentsAdmin(CommentsAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'content_type', 'object_title', 'ip_address', 'submit_date', 'is_public', 'is_removed')

    def object_title(self, obj):
        return unicode(obj.content_object)
    object_title.short_description = 'Title'
    object_title.admin_order_field = 'content_pk'

admin.site.unregister(Comment)
admin.site.register(Comment, CustomCommentsAdmin)
```